# Passing prop to modal - React Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to pass my movie data of a selected movie to my modal via props. But I am not having much luck.

I think this part of the code is where it goes wrong. Just started out with RN so I am not sure to be exact if the problem lies there.
[image]

Code for app.js
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/87c732c803a0a22b197740fd7adcbcdf

Code for movieDetail.js
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/618ab72e083f20f89f2421eb74fd95f4

Here is a screenshot of my console logs, as you can see is coming back undefined, but I am not sure how to solve the issue
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated to help me get my first pet project to done with RN

**UPDATE**:
so I adjusted the code a little in my setState so I can log what is going on 
[image]
**UPDATED CODE APP.JS** -> https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c69398e408f05cee2ecacd6f02096fa7
**UPDATED CODE MOVIEDETAIL.JS** ->
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6560364101fdefef6bdca3ecd9d7c7fc

As you can see from the screenshot it is logging 1 movie but I get an error coming from the movieDetail component saying that title is undefined
[image]

title is a reference to the api
[image]
What am I doing wrong ...

**UPDATED
I solved the issue**

Comment: setState is async, so console logging it right after wont show the updated value. setState can take a callback as a second argument that gets ran after the state gets updated. You should put your logs in there to check correctly.

Comment: Also don't name two completely different variables as `movieTrending`.

Comment: @MattAft. I am looking at the docs of RN but not seeing an example setting a callback in setState ...

Comment: RN docs tend to leave out a lot of things that are in the React docs, anything react related is more in depth in the React docs. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: @MattAft, just finish reading the docs but I am afraid is a bit complicated/confusing for me. not sure where to start exactly. any coded help would be much appreciated

Comment: It won't show too well as a comment but here's a simplified example: `this.setState({ selectedMovieTrending: 'Terminator' }, () => console.log(this.state.selectedMovieTrending))`

Answer (score 1):

Copying over my answer from [How to pass props to a modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53866458/how-to-pass-props-to-a-modal)

**** Not React Native but conceptually same in React ****

```
constructor(props) {

    super(props)


    this.state = {
      isModalOpen: false,
      modalProduct: undefined,
    }
}

//****************************************************************************/

render() {

    return (
        <h4> Bag </h4>
        {this.state.isModalOpen & (
          <Modal 
            modalProduct={this.state.modalProduct}
            closeModal={() => this.setState({ isModalOpen: false, modalProduct: undefined})
            deleteProduct={ ... }
          />
        )

        {bag.products.map((product, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
            <div>{product.name}</div>
            <div>£{product.price}</div>
            <div>
            <span> Quantity:{product.quantity} </span>
            <button onClick={() => this.props.incrementQuantity(product, product.quantity += 1)}> + </button>
            <button onClick={() => this.decrementQuantity(product)}> - </button> // <----
            </div>
        </div>
        ))}
    )
}

//****************************************************************************/

decrementQuantity(product) {

    if(product.quantity === 1) {
        this.setState({ isModalOpen: true, modalProduct: product })
    } else {
        this.props.decrementQuantity(product)
    }
}
```